# Groupby keeping all the information of a database

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, dask, dask-dataframe

let's say I have a dataframe A:

```
a0 a1    a2
1  1980  Y04
1  1983  Y08
1  1990  Y08
1  1980  Y08
1  1998  Y10
2  2003  Y02
3  1970  Y04
3  2009  Y10
3  1995  Y34
```

what I would like to do (in dask, but any suggestion, in Pandas as well, is helpful) is to make a groupby a0 retaining all the unique information contained in a1 and a2. In other words I would like to obtain the following:

```
a0  newa_1                        new_a2
1  [1980, 1983, 1990, 1998]  [Y04, Y08, Y10]
2  [2003]                          [Y02]
3  [1970,2009, 1995]               [Y04]
```

Thank you

Comment: This probably isn't the end goal of your process, though - what are you wanting to achieve?

Comment: @mdurant actually this is my goal but with a dask data frame rather than a pandas data frame. I think it involves somehow the Aggregation of dask as described here: https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.groupby.Aggregation.html

Comment: But why? The original form is a fine representation of the data. What would you want with a (python) list? They are not efficient or fast.

Comment: @mdurant the point is that my database is huge and I have to merge it to another very huge data frame. I would like to keep the number of a0 as low as possible (which is the number of the second data frame). In any case, I expect the resulting object to be a dataframe not a list right?

Comment: It is a dataframe containing lists, so not using numpy efficient packing. You should probably include the extra information about merging in your question, since that is your real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the unique function and reset the index to get a dataframe.

```
>>> df.groupby("a0").agg(newa_1=('a1',"unique"), new_a2=("a2","unique")).reset_index()

    a0  newa_1                      new_a2
0   1   [1980, 1983, 1990, 1998]    [Y04, Y08, Y10]
1   2   [2003]                      [Y02]
2   3   [1970, 2009, 1995]          [Y04, Y10, Y34]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `agg(col_name, unique)` after `groupby`:

```
df.groupby('a0').agg(newa_1=('a1','unique'), newa_2=('a2','unique'))
```

Output:

```
       newa_1                           newa_2
a0      
1   [1980, 1983, 1990, 1998]    [Y04, Y08, Y10]
2   [2003]                            [Y02]
3   [1970, 2009, 1995]           [Y04, Y10, Y34]
```